# cannot insert data to mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

so i'm working with grapesjs website builder and i want to store the data into database

here's code in index.php

```
var editor  = grapesjs.init({
storageManager:{
    type: 'remote',
    //end point where to save data
    urlStore: 'save.php',
    params: {},
    autosave: false,
  },

cmdm.add('save-db', {
run: function(editor, sender){
  sender && sender.set('active', 0);
  //turn off the button
  editor.store();
}
});
```

and here's save.php

```
<?php 

session_start();

include_once "../login/dbconf.php";
$dbconn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

if(isset($_POST['html'])){

$created = time();
$sql = "INSERT INTO templates (html, created) VALUES ('$_POST['html']', 
$created)";

if(mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql)){
    echo 'done'; 
}else{
    die("Error:". mysqli_error($dconn));
}

}
```

but i wont insert any data to my table which is templates, but in developer tools it said stored > object, what does it mean?

Comment: Please show error message. And use prepared statements.

Comment: change your query to `$sql = "INSERT INTO templates (html, created) VALUES ('$_POST[html]', '$created')";` then try

Comment: Change your query to use Prepared Statements. Easier and secure.